# Express +Mongoose push object into array of objects and adding two more rows into the object while inserting

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add a user inside the array objects, and add two more rows while inserting.

These are the two mongoose models that are used.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', {

      id:String, //the same id as user.id
      nick:String, //the same nick as user.nick

    }); 


module.exports = mongoose.model('Stores', {

  id: String,
  user: [{
    id: String, 
    nick: String,
    nr: Number,
    earnings: Number
  }],
  total: Number

});
```

So let's say I want to insert  a Users that is found by its id(not the auto-generated). (I have the removed the if (err) to make it readable).
This how i try to solve right now.

```
  Users.findOne({id : req.body.userid }, function(err, user) {

  //what user contains 
  user = { _id: 551fb0b688eacdf0e700000c,
      id: '123abc',
      nick: 'Foo',
      __v: 0 }

//I want to add this into the user and push it into exsisting array of        
objects that is 'users'
//But before that i want to add more info to the user,

//the desired format that I want to insert into 'users'
user = {id: '123abc',
       nick: 'Foo',
       nr: req.body.nr, //new
       earnings: req.body.earnings} //new

    Stores.update({id: req.params.id},
         {$push: { 'users' : user }}, function(err, store) {



    });

});


The current result is the following.
users: [
        {
            id: "123abc",
            nick: "Foo"

        }]
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema design as is creates at least one problem. What if a user updates their `nick`? Rather than only updating the `Users` collection you would also need to update every document in `Stores` that matches the user. You could use a `ref` and then [`populate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) to negate this concern.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', {
  id: String, //the same id as user.id
  nick: String, //the same nick as user.nick
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Stores', {
  id: String,
  users: [{
    user: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Users'
    },
    nr: Number,
    earnings: Number
  }],
  total: Number
});
```

Now the query would be:

```
Users.findOne({
  id: req.body.userid
}, function(err, user) {
  Stores.update({
    id: req.params.id
  }, {
    $push: {
      'users': {
        user: user,
        nr: req.body.nr, //new
        earnings: req.body.earnings
      }
    }
  }, function(err, store) {});
});
```

Later when you need to query `Stores`:

```
Stores
  .find(QUERY)
  .populate('users')
  .exec(function(err, stores) {...
  });
```